# How to get FormControl instance from ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, controls, directive, accessor

I've the following component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pc-radio-button',
    templateUrl: './radio-button.component.html',
    providers: [
        {provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => FieldRadioButtonComponent), multi: true}
    ]
})
export class RadioButtonComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    ...
}
```

I can assign and alter the value through these inputs:

```
<pc-radio-button [formControl]="formControl"></pc-radio-button>
<pc-radio-button [formControlName]="inputControlName"></pc-radio-button>
```

However I need the component to have the direct access to the assigned formControl, as I need to add styles depending on its status.

By creating an **@Input() formControl** does not solve the problem. As it does not cover the case when form control is assigned via formControlName.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It looks like injector.get(NgControl) is throwing a deprecation warning, so I wanted to chime in with another solution:

```
constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {
  ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
}
```

The trick is to also remove NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR from the providers array otherwise you get a circular dependency.

More information about this is in [this talk by Kara Erickson of the Angular team](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8).

Comment: This should be the accepted solution in 2019 with Angular 7.

Comment: Can you please show what's the deprecation warning?

Comment: FWIW, her presentation is totally worth your time. But if you are looking for the specific `NgControl` bits it starts around [19:07](https://youtu.be/CD_t3m2WMM8?t=1147)

Comment: To add to this answer: there is no need to remove NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR from providers, or to add ngControl.valueAccessor = this;

You can add NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR to the providers like this:
``` lang-js
{
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
```

then you can just inject NgControl in the constructor

Comment: Thank you @EricLiprandi, that was super useful.

Comment: @RemcoVlierman I get `Circular dependency in DI detected` when I do that

Comment: @Ties this forwardRef should prevent that, but maybe this behaviour has changed in  a later release. But it also could be your setup, would have to look into that before I can tell ;-)

Answer (score 29):

One possible solution is to get `NgControl` instance via `Injector`:

```typescript
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
export class PasswordComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit {
  ...
  ngControl: NgControl;

  constructor(private inj: Injector) {
    ...
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ngControl = this.inj.get(NgControl)
  }
```

then you can get status like

```typescript
ngControl.control.status
```

See also

- [Access valid value of custom form control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536108/access-valid-value-of-custom-form-control)

Answer (score 3):

Goes from my answer of this [stackblitz question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56576068/how-to-implement-reactive-form-as-custom-component-using-ng-value-accessor/56576631#56576631)

Another solution is add as provider NG_VALIDATORS. So, in our function validate we can store the control in a variable

```
public validate(c: FormControl) {
  if (!this.control)
    this.control=c;
  return null;
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6shurm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)