# setValidators in custom control without from reference in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-forms, angular4-forms, angular-validation

i have created a custom input control. I don't want to create any custom validation. I want to use default required, minLength, maxLength etc.I know i can do like this

```
this.form.controls["firstName"].setValidators([Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(30)]);
```

but i can't send form reference from parent component. How can i use setValidator inside textbox component.

```
// input-box.component.ts    
    import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-input-box',
      template:`<label >{{inputdata.label}}</label><br>
      <input type="text" required #textBox [value]="textValue" (keyup)="onChange($event.target.value)" />`,
      styleUrls: ['./input-box.component.less'],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputBoxComponent),
          multi: true
        },
        /*{
          provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputBoxComponent),
          multi: true,
        }*/]
    })
    export class InputBoxComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
      @Input() inputdata: any;
      private textValue: any = '';

      onChange(value) {
        this.textValue = value;
        this.propagrateChange(value);
      }

      private propagrateChange = (_: any) => { };

      writeValue(value: any) {
        if (this.inputdata.value) {
          this.textValue = this.inputdata.value;
          this.propagrateChange(this.inputdata.value);
        }

      }

      registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => any) {
        this.propagrateChange = fn;
      }


      registerOnTouched() { }
    }
```

use in different component

```
<app-input-box  name="textBoxParent_{{index}}"  [inputdata]="goaldata"  ngModel ></app-input-box>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to access the `FormControl` inside a class that wants to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` you have to change your usual implementation. You cannot register the class as `ControlValueAccessor` in the providers array AND inject the `FormControl` in the constructor. Because the FormControl will try to inject your class, and you will try to inject the control, which will create a circular dependency.

So the changes you need to make are as follows:

1. Remove `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` and `NG_VALIDATORS` from the `providers` array.
2. Inject `NgControl` in the constructor and set the control's ControlValueAccessor and Validators.

   ```
   constructor(@Self() ngControl: NgControl) { 
      ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
      ngControl.setValidators([Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(30)]
      ngControl.updateValueAndValidity()
   }
   ```

If you want to keep the validators specified by the consumer of your custom form component you need to modify the constructor to this:

```
constructor(@Self() ngControl: NgControl) { 
  const control = ngControl.control;

  let myValidators = [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)];
  let validators = control.validator
  ? [control.validator, ...myValidators]
  : myValidators;

  control.setValidators(validators)
  control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Check out the whole process explained by Kara Erickson (angular core) at AngularConnect 2017. [Link](https://youtu.be/CD_t3m2WMM8)

Comment: @TomaszKula, I watched that video which solves OP's use case without custom validation, but is there a way to also use a custom validation method that's defined in the custom form control's class?

Answer (score 0):

You could also leave your code as it is and simply get the `NgControl` from the `Injector` as follows:

```js
constructor(private injector: Injector) { 
}

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);
  const control = ngControl.control;
  // Do whatever you want with validators now:
  control.setValidators(validators)
  control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

You will need to use the lifecycle hook `ngAfterViewInit` otherwise the control will not yet be available.

Like this you skip the issues with circular dependencies and you can leave the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` and `NG_VALIDATORS` in the `providers` array.

---

See [a related question about injecting `NgControl` here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755958/how-to-get-formcontrol-instance-from-controlvalueaccessor).
Using the injector is suggested [in the answer from @yurzui here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45756292/1697459)