# Is there a way to avoid setTimeout?

Tags: angular, forms

I created a custom control which implements ControlValueAccessor and put that control into a template-driven angular form.

That's a form which allows to set start and stop dates for some activity to plan it and the start date in the past isn't valid. I have a validator for that so it shows an error when I click on that control. But when user opens a page he/she doesn't see any errors instantly because the user needs to click on that control to set it in the focused state.

I wanna do the "simple" thing - just automatically focus the control when the date in the past to get this control showing the error. The problem I encountered is that *ngAfterViewInit* in the parent component is called before *writeValue()* in the control. So I can set focus but there is no any errors shown. If I click manually on the other field ad then back - I see the error. The problem can be solved by wrapping my code for setting the focused state in a function and passing to setTimeout with zero interval.

That's not the first time I meet the problem like that when *ngAfterViewInit* is called too early but there is no controllable/synchronous way to make any operation later.

Is there any way to avoid setTimeout in *ngAfterViewInit*?

Here is the small example without setTimeout which shows that *writeValue* is called after *ngAfterViewInit*: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngafterviewinit-quirks

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried ngAfterViewChecked() ?

Comment: Of course. The problem is the same during the first call. Which call do I need? It seems like a hack.

Comment: I've added a small stackblitz example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "simple" thing would be to call `updateValueAndValidity` not just focus it. Be sure to call it in `ngAfterViewChecked`

```
<custom-control name="custom" [(ngModel)]="model.custom" minlength="100"></custom-control>

ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.formRef.form.controls['custom'].updateValueAndValidity();
    console.log(this.formRef.form.controls['custom'].valid);
  }
```

There is another solution if you don't want to have a reference to the control in the parent explained here in another SO question: [setValidators in custom control without from reference in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577602/setvalidators-in-custom-control-without-from-reference-in-angular)

Comment: `ngAfterViewChecked` is called many times so `updateValueAndValidity()` will also be called in the same way.