# Using formcontrol.setError() to propagate error to a custom control component

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor

I am have created a custom form control component using the controlValueAccesor interface provided by Angular.

Now I am using that custom component like this.

Parent:

```
<custom-control [formControl]="customControl"></custom-control>
```

it is working fine and as expected. The issue comes when I try to run `setErrors` method, since I want the error to propagate to the custom component so I can show error sent from outside of the component.

In the parent component that is using `custom-control` when I do this:

```
someValidation() {
  this.customControl.setErrors({
    myError: true
  })
}
```

Inside the template of my custom control component, I can see this

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div> {{form.errors}} </div> <!-- I want to be able to propage 'myError' here -->
</form>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I think your question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56061527/20813300)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can inject the current `FormControl` instance in your `custom-component`(which implements `ControlValueAccessor`) like this:

```js
// inside `custom-component`

get errors () {
  return this.ctrl.errors;
}

constructor (private ctrl: NgControl) { }
```

This solution is based on [how](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_directive.ts#L108) `FormControl` directive is implemented:

```js
constructor(
      /* ... validators ... */
      @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) valueAccessors: ControlValueAccessor[],
      /* ... */) {
    super();
    this._rawValidators = validators || [];
    this._rawAsyncValidators = asyncValidators || [];
    this.valueAccessor = selectValueAccessor(this, valueAccessors);
  }
```

---

If you'd like to read more about Angular Forms,I'd recommend checking out [A thorough exploration of Angular Forms](https://indepth.dev/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms/).

Comment: This was really helpful. Here I am adding an additional link with further information https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8

Comment: Glad I could help! Thanks for sharing that link